# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'http\\Client' not found http_request2

Tags: php, centos, payment, http-request2

I am trying to set up a safety pasarela using http_request2
(https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10111708/TVmLCykr)
Use composer

```
$ /usr/local/bin/composer info

guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.2.0 Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library
guzzlehttp/promises 1.4.0 Guzzle promises library
guzzlehttp/psr7 1.7.0 PSR-7 message implementation that also provides common utility methods
pear/http_request2 v2.4.2 Provides an easy way to perform HTTP requests.
pear/net_url2 v2.2.2 Class for parsing and handling URL. Provides parsing of URLs into their constituent parts (scheme, host, path etc.), URL generation, and resolving of relative URLs.
pear/pear_exception v1.0.1 The PEAR Exception base class.
transfer class for PHP
psr/http-client 1.0.1 Common interface for HTTP clients
psr/http-message 1.0.1 Common interface for HTTP messages
ralouphie/getallheaders 3.0.3 A polyfill for getallheaders.
```

I verified that I have pear installed
pear run-tests -r Running 0 tests TOTAL TIME: 00:00 0 PASSED TESTS 0 SKIPPED TESTS
my file:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;
$request->setRequestUrl('https://sandbox-mws.safetypay.com/mpi/api/v1/online-payment-requests');

$request->setRequestMethod('POST');
$body = new http\Message\Body;
$body->append('{
    "sales_amount": {
        "value": 50,
        "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "shopper": {
        "phone": {
            "phone_type": "Mobile",
            "phone_country_code": "51",
            "phone_number": "9999999999",
            "is_sms_enabled": false
        },
        "shopper_type": "Person",
        "first_name": "Joe",
        "last_names": "Doe"
    },
    "payment_ok_url": "https://www.safetypay.com/success.com",
    "payment_error_url": "https://www.safetypay.com/error.com",
    "filter_payment_by": "Channel(OL)",
    "merchant_set_pay_amount": false,
    "expiration_time_minutes": 120,
    "language_code": "EN",
    "custom_merchant_name": "M_TEST",
    "merchant_sales_id": "FirstTest",
    "requested_payment_type": "StandardorBoleto",
    "application_id": "1",
    "transaction_email": "jdoe@test.com",
    "send_email_shopper": false,
    "request_datetime": "2020-09-16T21:06:16.61"
}');
$request->setBody($body);
$request->setOptions(array());
$request->setHeaders(array(
  'X-Api-Key' => '5edd536ed98449692ef24e6883ebb95d',
  'X-Version' => '20200803'
));
$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();
echo $response->getBody();
```

But I keep getting the error:

> [php7:error] [pid 2653] [client 190.x.105.x:54x7] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'http\Client' not found in /var/www/html/safetyPay.php:3\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/html/safetyPay.php on line 3

Comment: Looks like you just got the wrong name for your class, if you go find in your vendor directory the class you are looking for you should find the right namespace and class